# Maximum size of input parsed by Antlr

Tags: java, antlr, large-files

I have a 2.5 GB file that I am trying to parse with Antlr in Java.  First I had an out of memory exception, so I increased the maximum heap size.  It then failed with this stack trace:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NegativeArraySizeException
    at java.util.Arrays.copyOf(Arrays.java:2882)
    at org.antlr.v4.runtime.ANTLRInputStream.load(ANTLRInputStream.java:123)
    at org.antlr.v4.runtime.ANTLRInputStream.<init>(ANTLRInputStream.java:86)
    at org.antlr.v4.runtime.ANTLRInputStream.<init>(ANTLRInputStream.java:78)
    at MyClass.runAntlr(MyClass.java)
```

My guess is that some index variable overflowed.

Is there an input stream that can handle an arbitrarily large file?  Or larger files that ANTLRInputStream?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's funny. I noticed the exact same thing myself the other day. The indexes are all integers instead along. Sam and I plan to integrate a fix for this at some point; if you look at branch, you can play with it now

https://github.com/parrt/antlr4/tree/long-intervals

Ter

Comment: This worked well.  The only change in my code was a minor int to long change.  Will this be released soon?

Comment: I'm not sure. Sam had concerns last we talked.